# can't able to change the state when back button pressed in react native

Tags: react-native

My Requirement when I press 1st time `showPopUp1` should be true and second time `showpopup1` will be false.

```
const [showPopUp1, setShowPopUp1] = useState(false);   
useBackHandler(() => {    
    setShowPopUp1(!showPopUp1)
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
const [showPopUp1, setShowPopUp1] = useState(false);    
 useBackHandler(() => { setShowPopUp1(!showPopUp1)}
```

don't return anything.

It will work.